# how to create list of location objects from Latlang array list in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, location-services

```
Location closestLocation; 
int smallestDistance = -1;
```

Assuming locations is an ArrayList()

```
   for(Location location : locations){
       int distance = Location.distanceBetween(closestLocation.getLatitude(),
                              closestLocation.getLongitude(),
                              location.getLatitude(),
                              location.getLongitude());
       if(smallestDistance == -1 || distance < smallestDistance){
           closestLocation = location;
           smallestDistance = distance;
       } }
```

but how to create list of locations from latlng list

Comment: Create class that have two attributes. Add getters, setters and constructor methods. Then create a `List` from this class.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create an arrayList of `LatLngs`. In the forloop you would then create an new `LatLng` oject and add to the arrayList. Here is how your code should look like:

```
ArrayList<LatLng> latLngArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Location location : locations){
        //create new latlng object
        LatLng newLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

        int distance = Location.distanceBetween(closestLocation.getLatitude(),
                closestLocation.getLongitude(),
                location.getLatitude(),
                location.getLongitude());
        if(smallestDistance == -1 || distance < smallestDistance){
            closestLocation = location;
            smallestDistance = distance;
        }

        //add new latlng to arraylist
        latLngArrayList.add(newLatLng);
```

Comment: Thank u for answering Ememobong AkpanEkpo....But my Actual question is how to create Arraylist<Locations> from the list of Arraylist<Latlng>(I have alredy latlng arraylist)......My task  is to  determine nearest locations(approx-1km) from list of locations from my current location.....